# Make a discord bot type in multiple channels

Tags: python, discord

so i created a discord bot but i can only type in 1 server and 1 channel how can i make it so the bot can type in multiple channels?

Error msg

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "main.py", line 20, in on_message
    amount = int (message.content)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '!Start'
```

Code:

```
import discord
import os

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
  print ('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  if message.author == client.user:
    return
 
  if message.content.startswith('!Start'):
    await message.channel.send('Hi')


client.run(os.getenv('TOKEN'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using discord.js or discord.py? Either way, unless you have a good reason, you are better of using

```
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "-")

@client.command()
async def Start(ctx):
    await ctx.send("Hi")
```

Sorry this does not answer your question, but it may provide a way to achieve the result with a different method. Also if you are using discord.py rewrite, doing `async def on_message(message):` without having `await client.process_commands(message)` at the end can break a lot of things, so try adding that to your function.